# C++ header issue involving functions and scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, scope, header-files

My problem is in the following C++ code. On the line with the 'cout' I get the error:

> "'number' was not declared in this scope".

.h

```
using namespace std;
class a{
     int number();
};
```

.cpp

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    cout << "Your number is: " << number() << endl;
    return 0; 
}

number(){
    int x = 1;
    return x;
}
```

Note: I'm aware this isn't the cleanest code. I just wanted to get the function working and refresh my memory on how to use headers.

Answer (score 1):

For minimal fix, **three** basic changes are necessary.

Proper implementation of the `number()` method

```
int a::number() {
    int x = 1;
    return x;
}
```

Proper invocation of the `number()` method

```
a aObject;
cout << "Your number is: " << aObject.number() << endl;
```

There are many other enhancements possible though.

---

Addition, as pointed out by @CPlusPlus, usable scope of `number()` method, for example declaring it `public`

```
class a{
  public:
     int number();
};
```

Comment: What about how the default `number` access being private?  The above call to invoke will fail until `number` is declared public.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your cpp file

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

void a::number()
{
    int x = 1;
    return x;
}


int main()
{

cout << "Your number is: " << a().number() << endl;
return 0; 
}
```

As for your header file replace `class` with a `struct`. The reason you are getting this error is because the compiler cant find the variable `number`. It is actually a method of a class.The reason you are replacing the `class` with a `struct` is because by default everything in a struct is public. So your header file called header.h should look like this

```
using namespace std;
struct a
{
     int number();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code.

1. The definition of the function number().

   As you declared, it is a member function of the class "a". In your .cpp, the class name should be used as a prefix to the function. I mean,

   ```
   a::number(){
       int x = 1;
       return x;
   }
   ```
2. As the function is a member of the class "a", there are only two ways of accessing it,

   1. If the function is a static function in the class, you can access it with :: operator. Like a::number().
   2. If the function is not a static function, that is true in your case, you should instantiate the object out of the class "a" and they use "." operator with the reference. I mean,

      ```
      a obj;
      obj.number().
      ```
3. Your function `number()` is declared in private scope. You may recall that by default the scope is a class is private unless you specify public or protected. So the private function number() cannot be used outside the declared class unless there is a friend to it.

   Below the code that I fixed,

   .h

   ```
   using namespace std;
   class a{
   public:
       int number();
   };
   ```

   .cpp

   ```
   using namespace std;
   #include <iostream>
   #include "header.h"

   a::number(){
       int x = 1;
       return x;
   }

   int main(){
       a obj;
       cout << "Your number is: " << obj.number() << endl;
       return 0; 
   }
   ```